# Chrome window.print() differences between Stable and Dev causing issues

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have the following code in a Chrome extension I wrote:

```
    chrome.tabs.update(newTab.id, {url: "javascript:window.print()"}, doAftermath);
} //End of a function

<snip!>

//Do nothing upon errors
function doAftermath(){
    if(chrome.runtime.lastError){
        //If the user doesn't Print or Cancel, but closes the
        //tab,
        // - OR -
        //If the original tab the user was on is now missing
        //
        //...ignore any errors
        return;
    }else{
        chrome.tabs.update(newTab.id, {url: "javascript:window.close()"}, doAftermath);
    }
} //doAftermath
```

I have a few machines, all with the same OS: Windows 7 HP SP1 x64. I noticed on the dev version of Chrome (38.0.2101.0 dev-m) that the tab doesnt close unless there's user action, which is what I want, however on the stable version (36.0.1985.125 m) the tab immediately closes upon open. It's as if `javascript:window.print()` completes on stable version but not on dev.

On a related note, should I use `chrome.tabs.update` to close the tab or `chrome.tabs.remove`?

Thank you very much for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. Fired the `chrome.tabs.update` event to `javascript:window.print()` only after the tab `status` was `complete`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should do another approach.. Executing JavaScript through `javascript:` URLs is a very roundabout way.

Instead, you can [inject this command as a content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript), and make use of [`run_at` parameter](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#run_at).

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(
  newTab.id,
  {
    code: "window.addEventListener('load', function(){ window.print() })",
    run_at: "document_end"
  },
  doAftermath
);
```

Note: at `document_end`, the resources like images are not yet loaded. That's why you should listen to `window.onload`. Injecting at `document_end` guarantees that the script runs before that event is fired.

Comment: Hi there. Sorry for the late reply. I ended up listening for `changeInfo.status === "complete"` with `chrome.tabs.onUpdated` before firing off anything else. This seemed to fix my issue.